# IOS 5 notifications style slider

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events

I am looking for a slider plugin which has functionality similar to the iOS 5 notifications where it sits on the top with a little handle visible and the user can drag it down and pull it back up.

I found a similar plugin called slide-in-menu which works rather nice but I am having trouble implementing it on a menu in the footer. The plugin is specifically designed for Header menus.

Demo of the above plugin: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sim/

I actually modified this to work in the footer by adding a negative value to the 3DTranslate but this modified version is missing the `touchMove` event. It is only reacting to taps.

I can post the plugin code but it is 120 lines long.